# IntentFilter in Xamarin gives error "java.exe exited with code 1"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-activity, intentfilter

I'm trying to understand how actions in xamarin work and i tried to add some of them to my activity. It builds with error "java.exe exited with code 1". I found that the same code works in my main launcher activity, but it doesn't compile when I'm adding it to the other activities.

I tried to search for answer, but there is no topic with that question, so i decide to write here for help.

This is my first time questioning btw ._.

this code builds

```
namespace XamarinLearningField
{
    [Activity(Label = "SomeApp", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategorySampleCode, "my.custom.category" })]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, Android.Views.View.IOnClickListener
    {
        TextView tvName;
        Button btnName;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

            tvName = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tvName);
            btnName = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnName);
            btnName.SetOnClickListener(this);

            Button btnTime = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnTime);
            Button btnDate = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.btnDate);

            btnTime.SetOnClickListener(this);
            btnDate.SetOnClickListener(this);
        }
}
```

this not

```
{
    [Activity(Label = "Data/Time info", MainLauncher = false)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "en.startandroid.intent.action.showtime","en.startandroid.intent.action.showdate" },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
    public class InfoActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Info_ActivityLayout);

          
            Intent intent = this.Intent;
            String action = intent.Action;
            String format = "", textInfo = "";

            if (action.Equals("en.startandroid.intent.action.showtime"))
            {
                format = "HH:mm:ss";
                textInfo = "Time: ";
            }
            else if (action.Equals("en.startandroid.intent.action.showdate"))
            {
                format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
                textInfo = "Date: ";
            }

            ...
}
```

Comment: I've had same issue, with **java exe.1**.  What I did was, update Visual Studio (if you are working in that IDE), and check if your Local Disk, or SSD card or wherever you have your project at, is close to full storage. If it is, delete something so it can have more free memory. Seems like it doesn't matter, but it did a fix for me.

Comment: @aca thank you for reply! I will try to do so and respond if it helps :)

Comment: Alright, hope it will. It's pretty frustrating error.

Comment: @aca well, it don't. Maybe I'm missing something with those attributes? Ugh..

Comment: you need to look at the build log to find the details about what is actually causing the error.  You may need to increase the log verbosity

Comment: @Jason thank you for your reply but I guess that I solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added "Exported = false" to Attributes of my extra Activity and it worked.

the code will be like that:

```
 [Activity(Label = "Data/Time info", Exported = false)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { "en.startandroid.intent.action.showtime","en.startandroid.intent.action.showdate" },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault })]
    public class InfoActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
       ...
```